# How to get image src, after click on other image

Tags: jquery, css, onclick

How to get image src, after click on other image?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img.getimage').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
  });
});
```

```css
.sinistra {
  width: 150px;
}

.getimage {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div id="mywrap">
    <img class="getimage" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/umut-pulat/tulliana-2/128/k-get-icon.png" /><br />

    <img class="sinistra" src="http://www.bicielettriche.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/bici-elettrica-piaggio.png" />
  </div>

  <br /><br /><br />

  <div id="mywrap">
    <img class="getimage" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/umut-pulat/tulliana-2/128/k-get-icon.png" /><br />

    <img class="sinistra" src="https://eradellabicicletta.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/bici-da-corsa-rb1000-team-edition.jpg" /><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

If clicked on img.getimage need to get src of image that included in same div with ID mywrap.
I can`t add add any other class or divs.

Here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Qartvela/as9osdvc/1/)

Comment: use $('#mywrap img') instead of $('img.getimage')

Comment: Id must be unique per page. You have a duplicate `mywrap`

Comment: have a look at .next and .siblings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/as9osdvc/10/), i used fiddle to search for `img.sinistra` sibling when getimage is clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('img.getimage').click(function () {
            alert($(this).siblings('img.sinistra').attr('src'));
        });
});
```

```css
.sinistra {
  width: 150px;
}
.getimage {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<div id="mywrap">
<img class="getimage" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/umut-pulat/tulliana-2/128/k-get-icon.png"/><br />

<img class="sinistra" src="http://www.bicielettriche.bikeitalia.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/bici-elettrica-piaggio.png"/>
</div>

<br /><br /><br />

<div id="mywrap">
<img class="getimage" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/umut-pulat/tulliana-2/128/k-get-icon.png"/><br />

<img class="sinistra" src="https://eradellabicicletta.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/bici-da-corsa-rb1000-team-edition.jpg"/><br />
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this with jQuery, but one way is to select the parent of that icon, and then select the child image with the `sinistra` class.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('img.getimage').click(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().children('.sinistra').attr('src'));
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/as9osdvc/3/)**

**OR**

You can simply select the `sinistra` sibling

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('img.getimage').click(function () {
    alert($(this).siblings('.sinistra').attr('src'));
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/as9osdvc/13/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use closest() with find() like so, also id should be unique, don't name all container divs with the same id of mywrap, give them a shared class if you really need it, but currently neither is necessary:

```
$('img.getimage').click(function () {
            //Get the parent div of the link clicked
            let containerDiv = $(this).closest('div');
            let srcVal = $(containerDiv).find('.sinistra').attr('src'));
        });
```